# Unable to Try or Install from Lubuntu Live CD

Tags: system-installation, intel, live-cd

I have an Powerspec B707 with a [10 year old](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42408/intel-desktop-board-dh55tc.html) Intel [dh55tc motherboard design](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023741/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html), i5 processor in the LGA1156 socket, 8 gigs of ram, and integrated graphics.

When I boot with a Lubuntu livecd and select try, install, or check for errors, it sits for a bit, then my pc shuts down. I can progress a little further with the memory test. It'll start the test, then the display will flicker and the pc shuts down.

I've tried various boot options such as nomodeset, noapic, and acpi=off to no avail. I've tried Lubuntu 16.04, 18.04, and 19.04 live CDs. I haven't tried other Linux distribution or booting from USB, and am looking for guidance on troubleshooting.

Edit: I've tried a bootable USB, and I also tried Fedora. Same issue every time: as soon as it tries to install or load the OS for a try out, the system just shuts down.

Edit2: I removed one of the 4gb sticks of ram and was able to actually run the live lubuntu.  I was able to use it and ran several cpu tests with no issues. When I open a web browser, however, it dies.  (Haven't tried much else.) Also, when I try to install it dies after I select full install with 3rd-party software, etc. I'm leaning towards a motherboard issue. Is there anything I can run in the live lubuntu mode that would help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Thanks, these were checked and no issues making live cds or live usbs.  I suspect some type of hardware issue but looking for guidance on troubleshooting this.

Comment: A review of the manuals https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42408/intel-desktop-board-dh55tc.html for your motherboard shows no support for Linux. Nevertheless, I would try making LiveUSBs for the LTS (i.e., 18.04) versions of the Ubuntu flavours https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours starting with the Ubuntu itself (as Lubuntu failed).

Comment: This page is a bit old but indicates that, despite the board not officially supporting Linux, it should work: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Intel_DH55T. Will try Ubuntu itself but suspect I'll run into the same issue.